# Slack App - Is it possible to customize blocks depending on users?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm working on a Slack App and I would like to customize some messages depending on the users who view them.

I know about [chat.postEphemeral](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postEphemeral) API method, but the visual rendering is not at all pleasant (at least for my app layout).

The best solution would be to add some blocks which can be viewed/customized depending on the users who view them. Is there some way to do that?

**Edit:**

After several researches I did a [new feature proposal to enrich the messages](https://twitter.com/DanieleiCC/status/1347120916254355457) to Slack to have something potentially new which can be helpful to someone else. Everybody is welcome to the discussion to improve the proposal.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not. When you're posting messages into a conversation using `chat.postMessage`, the content of that message is the same for all users.

You've a few options, but they really depend on your app's flow.

- Use `chat.postEphemeral`, as you've mentioned already
- Render a modal view, which gives you the User ID *before* you construct the view, allowing you to customise it. The downside here is that it will require some user interaction like clicking a button before you can present the modal.
- Render the content inside an App Home, which again will provide user ID, but this exists outside the context of a conversation, which might be important for your app.

Other than that, I'm afraid you'll need to stick with a generic message.

Comment: Yes, that's why I opened a new feature proposal to Slack: https://twitter.com/DanieleiCC/status/1347120916254355457